# Objective-C If this UIScrollView is this size

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have two UIScrollViews and they have different sizes. How do I do an condition saying `if (UIScrollView is this size) { do this }else{ do this }`

Comment: check frame ....scrollview has different name? right...

Comment: do this at viewdidappear or do this after scrollview scrolls ?

Comment: Its always better to set tag to the scrollview and check for this tag to performsomething.Or if you want to  implement a specific logic,then make the question more clear.

Comment: where you do comparing both scrollView .

Answer (score -1):

I m not getting what you really need. As far as i can get you need 2 different operation on two UIScrollView. If that's the case u can specify 2 different IBOutlets for both the UIScrollView and access them accordingly.
like 
[image]

**You can get size of UIScrollView using .**

```
scrollView.frame.size.height
```

Hope It helps.. Happy Coding ..:)

Comment: How does this answer the question? If you don't understand what the OP is asking, how can you provide an answer?

Comment: Ok i will take it as a  good experience and would keep in mind for future.. Thanks anyways.. Both of u.. :)